# How to drop columns other than the ones mentioned?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know there is a function .drop() which removes the columns I mention inside the parentheses. I need the opposite: to remove all the columns except the ones I indicate.

I tried:
df = df.drop(columns != ['Plant', 'Date', 'Type'])
hoping I would get my dataframe only with those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's simpler to directly select the columns you want to keep:

```
df = df[['Plant', 'Date', 'Type']]
```